# Mypy recognize a class as a function

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, mypy

When running mypy on the following file:

```
from multiprocessing import Event

my_event = Event()
```

I encounter the following error:

`error: Missing named argument "ctx" for function "Event"`

`Event()` is a class constructor, and doesn't take arguments. Why does mypy identify it as a function? And where does `ctx` come from?

Comment: What version of mypy are you running? I don't seem to be able to reproduce your error, at least using mypy 0.630.

Comment: I'm on mypy 0.521, that could be it.